# Three rings (wreaths?) symbol in XIX century Russia

Tags: russia

On some buildings in Moscow (and other cities in European part of Russia) there are carvings of three interconnected wreaths.

For example, some are on the Pushkin Museum building on Prechistenka:

[image] 
[image]
[image]

This building was erected around 1814, but unfortunately I didn't find information about the meaning of the carvings (apart from the shield with emblem of the building original owners). As usual, people are blaming Masons and I wouldn't be surprised if it is a part of masonic symbolism, however, I didn't find anything exactly like that. I.e., IOOF symbol is similar, but it should be chain which would look different. It is also not Borromean Rings which should be interlocked.

So, where does this symbol come from?

A couple more images from other sites:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Very interesting! I saw these rings many times, but never asked myself what they represent. A search in Russian language yielded a lot of esoteric nonsense, as well as Masonic references and an assertion that the rings represent the Trinity; the latter one would make sense if not for elaborate ornaments inside some of the rings. If you are confident that the ring originated in 1814 try some reference on Napoleonic wars: that year was the year of the victory over Napoleon for Russia. I couldn't connect via online searches the rings with that victory though.

Comment: Oh, and one more conjecture I couldn't connect with the rings in a brief search: in Imperial Russia, besides the Christian Trinity, there was a notion of Tri-Unity of "Православие, Самодержавие, Народность", roughly translated as "Christian Orthodoxy, Absolute Monarchy, and Common Nationality". This may very roughly correspond to the West's Church, Noble, and Peasant classes, except that the Russian slogan proclaimed tri-unity of those. The victory over Napoleon was widely attributed to that tri-unity: the war effort by nobles, the guerilla war by peasants, and God's blessing via the Church.

Comment: @Michael Yes, I searched on this issue for a few hours in Russian internet (including official info about the buildings) and all I found are unsupported references to Masons with no further elaboration, and, as I mentioned, if it is a masonic symbol, it is not an obvious one.

Comment: I would consider it to be merely an ornamentation if not the fact that it is present in the centre of the buildings' façades, often being almost the only decoration. Pushkin Museum building was rebuilt after 1812 war and there is no information if it has been altered afterwards. I found photos taken in 1910 and all the ornaments are there, so that seems legit. The other two examples are in Tver and were built around late XIX - early XX centuries.

Comment: @Michael "Christian Orthodoxy, Absolute Monarchy, and Common Nationality" was proposed by Uvarov around 1830's, so it's a highly unlikely explanation.

Comment: I wouldn't put too much faith in anything attributed to Masons on Russian web: there are too many "Jewish Masons" conspiracy nuts in Russia these days. Any unexplained symbols may be attributed to Masons by them. Even though the early 1800s era did indeed see much Masonic influence, mainstream Russian web is an awfully poor source on that.

Comment: @Michael totally agree

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that the slogan was later than 1812 war. I thought it was one of those patriotic slogans actually used in Patriotic War; a search prompted by your answer points to the December revolt rather than the war as the reason for the slogan.

Comment: It's definitely not a Masonic symbol. It may be a laurel wreath representative of Apollo and/or Daphne. The significance of the triple interleaving may be associated with traditional Russian triple wedding bands.

Comment: @Michael - attributing all sorts of stuff to masons isn't a uniquely Russian phenomenon... American far left suffers from it to a great degree.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens - you're not from Russia, so it may seems strange to you, but "Zhido-Masony" concept in Russia has virtually nothing to do with _real_ Masons and thus whether the symbol was truly masonic isn't really relevant. Oh, and the first person pointing to my Gravatar will suffer the wrath of Trilateral Commission.

Comment: I always accept the word of the *all-seeing eye*.

Comment: Just wild speculation, but 3 laurels would seem to symbolize victories, with the bar representing unity. This could be similar to the symbolism of the 3 crowns on the Russian Imperial Coat of Arms: the conquering of Kazan, Astrakhan, and Siberia and the unification of the Russian Empire.

Answer (score 2):

After hard research, I finally found some interesting resources on [this page](http://via-midgard.info/news/20837-oni-splosh-i-ryadom-povsyuduznaki-masonov-i.html).

[image]

This rings were **religius symbols, they represented The Holy Trinity**. They represent The Father, The son and The Holy spirit. A circle is an endless line having no beggining and no end symbolising God's eternity. The rings - three ribbon swirls were similar symbol(trinity).

[image]

The same building, again three circles. In the center of the image is [**Dyonisus**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dionysus), god of grape harvest and winemaking. We are talking about trinity again.

[image]

And finally yes, you were right about masons. They talked about trinity of everything. Also on this picture you can see lions. They seemed to symbolize the secret meetings - nobody will go beyond the building and it is not available to those from outside of the building.

Comment: Well, the link you provide is exactly one of those Masonic conspiracy rants I'd rather not trust. There are no references to any trustable sources, the fact that three is a special number in Christianity (and for Masons as well) would be an obvious explanation, however the question specifically addresses this particular kind of ornament and it'd be useful to know where it has originated and what exactly is the meaning.

Comment: On the other hand, if someone really is following you, you're not paranoid are you. Perhaps the building WAS used by a group of Masons. Just saying, just because 'everyone' thinks of the Masonic symbol conspiracy fruitcakes as crazy, doesn't make them crazy, just tasty.

Answer (score -2):

Before Russia was an empire, it was a collection of duchies, each kinged by a duke. When all these dukes adopted Christianity, which happened at around the same time, they used a crest of three circles in a triangle as a sign of their fidelity to the conversion. Supposedly this was to answer to the trinity, but in truth it probably dates back to being a Mongol symbol from the time when Russia was ruled by the Golden Horde. The dukes just re-adapted the symbol to mean the holy Trinity. In the circles were placed their names, oaths and personal badges. Strahlemberg "Description de l'Empire Russe" vol I p. 240 (1757)

Comment: Is there any indication that the symbol was used before Peter I?

Comment: @Anixx Nope, before Peter the Great, Russia was called "Muscovy" and was pretty much a dirt patch with a bunch of log cabins. They didn't have books or stone buildings or anything like that. High tech in old Muscovy was having like a boat or something like that.

Comment: `Nope, before Peter the Great, Russia was called "Muscovy"` Ah, then I guess we should start removing references to the 200 year old Tsardom of Russia from history books...

Comment: @YannisRizos All books written before about 1720 talk about the duchy of Muscovy as just that, Muscovy. The idea of Russia, as we know it today, was invented during the reign of Peter the Great.